# What's the stoichiometric ratio of Kerosene to a mixture of 50% water and 50% hydrogen peroxide

Tags: stoichiometry, combustion, mixtures

So I'm wanting to do some testing with combustion of certain liquids, and I'd like to know what the right ratio is for these liquids. What I'm going to be using is regular kerosene (NOT RP-1) and 50% pure hydrogen peroxide. If you could go over how you got your results, that would be great, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Working with 50 % hydrogen peroxide and not being able to calculate it seems to me a bit controversial.

[Kerosene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerosene) contains hydrocarbons typically with 9-16 carbon atoms. If we take $\ce{C12H26}$ as an representative:

$\ce{C12H26 + 37 H2O2 -> 12 CO2 + 50 H2O}$

It leads to approximately (assuming integer molar masses give enough accuracy due unknown variables):

- $12 \times \pu{12 g} + \pu{26 g} = \pu{170 g}$ of kerosene
- $37 \times \pu{34 g} \approx \pu{1260 g}$ of 100 % hydrogen peroxide, i.e. $\pu{2520 g}$ of 50 % one
- This leads to mass ratio roughly  1 : 15. The ratio will somewhat vary with the particular kerosene composition.
- As [kerosene density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerosene) is $\pu{0.78–0.81 g/mL}$ and for
  [50% hydrogen peroxide](https://www.fishersci.com/shop/products/hydrogen-peroxide-50-stabilized-certified-fisher-chemical/H341500) it is $\pu{1.2 g/mL}$, the typical volume ratio would be 1 : 9.9.

I assume the practical ratio would be higher due possible hydrogen peroxide decomposition without oxygen being used for burning.

Considering all the water to evaporate, no wonder they used 100 % hydrogen peroxide as the oxidant, with all the danger it brought. It is unclear how intense the oxidation can be with 50 %.